# Embedding Flash Media Services (Red5) and Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, security, architecture, red5

An architectural question.

My site needs to allow the user to record video and upload it to the "site". I've been poking around a fair bit and it seems I *have* to use some kind of media server to achieve this aim. As I'm introducing this secondary server into the system (I seek to embed the flash app residing on this server into the HTML delivered by the site) it occurs to me that this broadens the scope of security a lot. What scares me is attackers trying to embed the flash app themselves or attempting to impersonate clients (or anything else I haven't thought of yet!).

I was therefore wondering how people secure their applications with such an architecture. Sure I can do what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13006632/1143), a decent band-aid for now but afaik the domain information can technically be falsified by the client.

I could separate out the auth of the site giving me a WebServer, an AuthServer and a MediaServer enabling the MediaServer to separately auth. Getting the user to log into both sites is obviously onerous and passing around the user's login creds and securing all connections sounds ugly and averse to best practice.

As far as I can see my best bet is some kind of temporary token that the auth server creates. So the website kicks the auth server after logging in to generate the token which the site can then pass to the media server (as part of the flash vars) and the MediaServer itself can use to double check against the auth server.

I'm relatively new to Red5, Flash and web security so I was wondering if the following sounds sane, secure and/or necessary. Also if anyone knows of decent tools to use for such an auth system and whether there is something already kicking about in ASP.NET auth for such a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

the solution provided in your link ... you should read my second comment.
The first about virtual hosts is wrong! My comment does actually tell you (at least one) solution to secure your app.

You could for example pass a SESSION_ID in the connect method to Red5. The user would get the SESSION_ID from another webservice call before he invokes the record or playback method.

The SESSION_ID might be even some kind of temporary token, that is only valid for 15 minutes and only usable a single time for exactly that video. How far you implement that is a matter of how secure your mechanism needs to be.

Sebastian

Comment: a good reference implementation for security might be the OAuth spec. If you really want to put a lot of effort into it, I would suggest trying to apply some standard APIs, maybe a later HTTP Streaming using pure HTML5 might be easier to merge to if you are using common patterns.